# Google oauth Sign in using your Google account

Tags: oauth

If I go to the ["Test your AuthSub registration" page](https://www.google.com/accounts/UpdateDomain), it asks if my website can access my calendar.  But what I want is only to "Sign in using your Google account".

How do I tell Google that I don't want to access someone's calendar, but only want them to sign in using their Google account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be looking into oAuth, it is an authentication protocol while exchanging data with google services using APIs, for signing in using google account you should look into "Federated Login for Google Account Users"
Please read the following article.
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: Thanks sapan!  I was just waiting to see if anyone had anything further to say before "closing" this question out.

Answer (score 3):

While labeled as 'experimental', Google's OAuth2 implementation is a simpler, approach to API authentication that is particularly friendly to javascript clients (while also easier to use by server-side deployments): http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html

Comment: Thank you breno - I'll check it out!

Comment: Can anyone point me to a working document which describes the Hybrid approach (oAuth2 with Federated Login)?  I am having problems implementing with oAuth2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333007/performing-google-federated-login-oauth2-after-initial-authentication

Answer (score 1):

As OpenID 2.0 is depreciated, you should be looking at this link (OAuth 2.0 for Login): https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Juan.  Will do.